# Why does my Javascript canvas not move on keyboard input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, keyboard-events

So recently I got into Javascript and I watched some few tutorials and read a StackOverflow Question asking a simular thing.

For some reason my Canvas Object wont move and I did seemingly everything like many other examples.

My Code:

```js
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
    switch (event.keyCode) {
      case 87:
      alert("w");
        break;
      case 65:
      alert("a");
        break;
      case 83:
      alert("s");
        break;
      case 68:
      moveRight();
        break;
      case 38:
      alert("up");
          break;
      case 37:
      alert("right");
        break;
      case 39:
      alert("left");
        break;
      case 40:
      alert("down");
        break;
  }
})

function moveRight() {
  var element = document.getElementById("plr");
  element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
}

// w = 87
// a = 65
// s = 83
// d = 68
// up = 38
// right = 37
// left = 39
// down = 40
```

```css
#bg{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 700px;
  width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  top: -10px;
}
#plr{
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body onload="">
    <canvas id="bg"></canvas>
    <canvas id="plr"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

I know that Im making a dumb/small mistake somewhere but I cannot find it.
Thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following fixes your problem...

```
  <canvas id="plr" style="left: 50px;top: 300px;"></canvas>
```

The reason why it doesn't work the way you've done it is because you haven't initialised style.left;

Setting left in css doesn't put that value in style.left

The following doesn't work which is what you are doing:

```js
console.log("left=" + document.getElementById("player").style.left);
```

```css
#player {left:100px}
```

```html
<canvas id="player">
```

Console will just print "left=" and no value.

So, when you do the following

```
element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
```

What you end up doing is parseInt("") - 5 + 'px' which gives you "NaNpx" and therefore doesn't move.

You can initialise style.left by applying it to the canvas directly as shown below:

```js
console.log("left=" + document.getElementById("player").style.left);
```

```html
<canvas id="player" style="left:100px">
```

The console output will become left=100px

Which means your existing moving player code will now work.

If prefer not to set left style within the HTML then alternative is to use element.getBoundingClientRect(); and calculate left from that

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Answer (score 0):

in `element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 5 + 'px'` try `(parseInt(element.style.left.slice(0, -2)) - 5).toString()` in the change were slicing the 'px' part out then converting string to int, after the operation x - 5 where converting the output to string and concatenating it with 'px'.

Answer (score 0):

There are two related problems associated with the moveRight function in this statement:

```
element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
```

- initially the style of the div is not set - the CSS class defines where the element is to be (50px) but the element.style.left has not been set
- even if it had been set at the start it would have been of this form: 50px - i.e. not a number so parseInt will not give us 50.

what we want to know, regardless of whether the style.left property has been set or not is where the canvas is in relation to its parent. We can use offsetLeft (see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft

> The HTMLElement.offsetLeft read-only property returns the number of pixels that the upper left corner of the current element is offset to the left within the HTMLElement.offsetParent node

as this gives us an actual number we can subtract the 5 from it then add in the px string and use that to set the style.left:

```
  element.style.left = (element.offsetLeft - 5) + 'px';
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" dir="ltr">
  <head>
 <!--   <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
    #bg{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 700px;
  width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  top: -10px;#bg{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 700px;
  width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  top: -10px;
}
#plr{
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 300px;
}
}
#plr{
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 300px;
}
    </style>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="bg"></canvas>
    <canvas id="plr"></canvas>
<script>
   document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
    switch (event.keyCode) {
      case 87:
      alert("w");
        break;
      case 65:
      alert("a");
        break;
      case 83:
      alert("s");
        break;
      case 68:
      moveRight();
        break;
      case 38:
      alert("up");
          break;
      case 37:
      alert("right");
        break;
      case 39:
      alert("left");
        break;
      case 40:
      alert("down");
        break;
  }
})

function moveRight() {
  var element = document.getElementById("plr");
  element.style.left = (element.offsetLeft - 5) + 'px';
}

// w = 87
// a = 65
// s = 83
// d = 68
// up = 38
// right = 37
// left = 39
// down = 40
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```